# What is [root@server ~#] as opposed to [root@name ~]#

Tags: command-line, unix, terminal, shell

What is `[root@server ~#]` as opposed to `[root@name ~]#`?
Notice the `#` is inside the bracket on the first one and outside on the second one.
What is the first one and what command in a terminal gets you to `[root@server ~#]`?
I'm seeing `[root@server ~#] useradd danny` in a vsftpd tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a typo in that particular guide.

Comment: Thank you Ignacio. The author is on another site, I'll see if I can reach them there.